# How does Angular know there was an error on an $http request?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

How does the $http function of Angular "know" the response was an error in an ASP.NET request? I'm looking at the response headers but don't see anything that looks relevant.

I have this service in Angular:

```
service.getStuff = function () {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: './GetJsonData.aspx?RequestType=Stuff'
        //That asp.net page returns json on success, but a regular
        //asp.net error page on failure. I know there's better ways,
        //but ignore that, that's not the question here.
    });
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
$scope.reloadData = function () {
            MyService.getStuff().success(function (response) {
                alert("good");
            })
            .error(function (response) {
                alert("bad");
            });
        };
```

That asp.net page is (correctly) throwing an exception on bad input and angular is (correctly) recognizing it as an error. But I can't figure out it knows there was an error. Is there some header that's it looking for? In the success case I receive json and in the failure case i receieve HTML, so as a human; but the angular code doesn't *know* that. So how is it recognizing this was an error?

Comment: [**AngularJs - $HTTP**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) - From that documentation (paraphrased): `error` is called if an error occurs or the server returns response with an **error status**. A response status code **between 200 and 299** is considered a **success status** and will result in the success callback being called. - Further readon on [**HTTP Status Codes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) - If you realy want to know what goes on under the hood, try to make requests with pure JavaScript and check out what codes are returned when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses the HTTP status codes. This is standard behavior for restful clients and services.